# SharePoint 2013 Custom FBA page

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I already have implemented Default login page , what i want to achieve is get rid of the default page[image]

and replace it with my company logo and general info and then have an hyperlink(partner login) to go to forms  authentication

so i followed this article
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx
 what is the physical location of this file ~/_layouts/Contos.SharePoint...

[image]

1) Where is the default login page and how do i replace it , and for the forms page I have gone ahead and replace that in the virtual directory of the site collection(_forms/default.aspx with custom page) is this the rite way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be developing a SharePoint solution that contains your login page.  Deploy the solution to the farm.  Once the solution is deployed, then reference your login page with the format of "/_layouts/Solution.Folder/LoginPage.aspx".

Comment: does it matter if it is for 2013 ?

Comment: Nothing changes between 2010 an 2013 in this respect.

Comment: confused , will it change the default " sign in" page or will it change the page after you select the forms authentication" option

Comment: You'll create a new sign in page (in your own solution, with it's own file name), deploy it to the farm in a WSP, then manage the Web Application in Central Administration, select Authentication Providers, and finally provide the path to your custom sign in page ("/_layouts/SolutionName/loginPage.aspx").